# Error: package does not exist. Is the issue code related?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, rhel

I'm trying to compile Java code in RHEL 7 and i get this kind of errors

```
error: package org.apache.xml.serialize does not exist
import org.apache.xml.serialize.Method;

symbol:   class SistPrint
  location: class CrearSocketMIE
./GRP/Comunicaciones/ComMIE/CrearSocketMIE.java:187: error: cannot find symbol
    public SocketCliente getSocketMIE(int lan) {
```

and so on, when i try in Ubuntu i don't get them... what am i seeing? is this code related or is the SO environment?. Both have the same jdk version (jdk1.8.0_65), how can they behave differently?

What config am i missing (sure JAVA_HOME is already set) is there anything else?, I have a Make file that does different things depending the environment, really strange.

What do you think?

Comment: you'll need to import the right packages and libraries in your project.

Comment: You're using an external library. Its jar needs to be in the build path (classpath of `javac`).

Comment: Your ubuntu environment probably has its classpath correctly set whereas your RHEL doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

The error you have reported shows that the compiler is unable to find [Apache Xerces](https://xerces.apache.org/) library in [the classpath](http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html).

Make sure that all required libraries (they are jar-files) are included to the [classpath command line parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options) when your compiler (javac) is running.